# RDP Disconnects when checking Printers option

Tags: printing, rdp

When I RDP into my Azure VM it quickly disconnects when I select Local Resources and the checkbox for Printers. Therefore I can't get printing pass through to work. I can RDP fine without checking the printers box.  Looking for assistance in troubleshooting as I'm out of ideas.

OS: Win Pro 8.1
Printers: Dell 3100cn, Dell 1600
Installed printer drivers on remote VM

If I turn off the print spooler on the VM and check the printers on the RDP connection it won't kick me out. I can turn print spooler back on and it won't disconnect but I don't have access to my local printers when connecting this way.

Answer (score 2):

It might mean that you don't have suitable printer drivers on server. However there are third-party software that enables you printer redirection over RDP such as [tsprint](http://www.terminalworks.com/remote-desktop-printing).

Comment: Thanks John I will take a look. I've installed the same drivers that i have working on my local printer (both windows 8.1). I'm not sure if a port is not getting passed through since they are custom ports. I if I turn off the print spooler in the RDP VM i can log in and when i turn it back on it doesn't kick me out but my printers are not available at that point to select. I will take a look at the TSPrint. I'm also looking at site to site vpn so then i won't have to rely on the rdp pass through.